# How can I get the Advanced Database Crawler to index the item name

Tags: search, sitecore

I'm trying to switch my Sitecore application's search from the "old" indexes (Sitecore.Data.Indexing) to the "new" indexes (Sitecore.Search).

I used to have an index that explicitly listed the fields that I wanted indexed.  The Item's name was one of these:

```
<field target="name">@name</field>
```

The new indexes, along with the Advanced Database Crawler allow you to have include fields and exclude fields.  I've set the index IncludeAllFields value to false, as there are more fields I want to leave out than I want to index.  And I add the fields I want via includes:

```
<include hint="list:IncludeField">
    <!-- Field 1 -->
    <fieldId1>{396CA18D-0E46-437E-9237-C10FDB217666}</fieldId1>
    <!-- Field 2 -->
    <fieldId2>{396CA18D-0E46-437E-9237-C10FDB217666}</fieldId2>
    <!-- Field 3 -->
    <fieldId3>{CC45947E-A22C-44E3-9652-32E519DABC7F}</fieldId3>
</include>
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to add the item's name with these new indexes.  As far as I know the item's name isn't in a field.  I tried looking at a sample item's fields after calling item.Fields.ReadAll() and looking through them all, but I couldn't see the item's name.

Is the item's name in a field that I can add to the include list, or is there another approach?

Thanks

Comment: After looking at the indexes using Luke, I see that there is a "__name" field that is being indexed.  I guess the ADC indexes this anyway and you don't have to add the field.

Comment: topher, you should probably just answer your own question and mark it answered. =]