# How to add a specific content item using Advance Database Crawler?

Tags: search, sitecore

I read this question: [How can I get the Advanced Database Crawler to index the item name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211496/how-can-i-get-the-advanced-database-crawler-to-index-the-item-name)

But want to ask that it I want to index a content item folder which is under: /sitecore/content/Data/MyNewsFeed
and I want to create an index on it, I wrote this code in my .config file:

```
    <configuration xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <databases>
      <database id="master" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.Database, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>
          <obj type="Sitecore.Data.$(database).$(database)HistoryStorage, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <param connectionStringName="$(id)" />
            <EntryLifeTime>30.00:00:00</EntryLifeTime>
          </obj>
        </Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>
        <Engines.HistoryEngine.SaveDotNetCallStack>false</Engines.HistoryEngine.SaveDotNetCallStack>
      </database>
    </databases>
    <search>
      <configuration>
        <indexes>
          <index id="web" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="folder">master</param>
            <Analyzer ref="search/analyzer" />
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <master type="Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler.Crawlers.AdvancedDatabaseCrawler,Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler">
                <Database>master</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/content/Data/MyNewsFeed</Root>
                <IndexAllFields>true</IndexAllFields>

                <fieldCrawlers hint="raw:AddFieldCrawlers">
                  <fieldCrawler type="Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler.FieldCrawlers.LookupFieldCrawler,Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler" fieldType="Droplink" />
                  <fieldCrawler type="Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler.FieldCrawlers.DateFieldCrawler,Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler" fieldType="Datetime" />
                  <fieldCrawler type="Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler.FieldCrawlers.DateFieldCrawler,Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler" fieldType="Date" />
                  <fieldCrawler type="Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler.FieldCrawlers.NumberFieldCrawler,Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler" fieldType="Number" />
                </fieldCrawlers>
                <!-- If a field type is not defined, defaults of storageType="NO", indexType="UN_TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" are applied-->
                <fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldTypes">
                  <!-- Text fields need to be tokenized -->
                  <fieldType name="single-line text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="multi-line text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="word document" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="html" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="rich text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="memo" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <!-- Multilist based fields need to be tokenized to support search of multiple values -->
                  <fieldType name="multilist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="treelist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="treelistex" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="checklist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <!-- Legacy tree list field from ver. 5.3 -->
                  <fieldType name="tree list" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                </fieldTypes>
              </master>
            </locations>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
    </search>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

SO basically I targeted the root to MyNewsFeed folder. Is there any other way I can achieve this? Thanks!

I added this snippet:

```
 <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
          <master type="Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler.Crawlers.AdvancedDatabaseCrawler,Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler">
            <Database>master</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore/content/Data/myNewsFeed</Root>
            <IndexAllFields>false</IndexAllFields>
            <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
              <template1>{GUID here}</template1>
              <template2>{GUID here}</template2>
            </include>
            <fieldCrawlers hint="raw:AddFieldCrawlers">
              <fieldCrawler type="Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler.FieldCrawlers.LookupFieldCrawler,Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler" fieldType="Droplink" />
              <fieldCrawler type="Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler.FieldCrawlers.DateFieldCrawler,Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler" fieldType="Datetime" />
              <fieldCrawler type="Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler.FieldCrawlers.DateFieldCrawler,Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler" fieldType="Date" />
              <fieldCrawler type="Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler.FieldCrawlers.NumberFieldCrawler,Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler" fieldType="Number" />
            </fieldCrawlers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're config is correct, but you need to tell it what template types to include in the index, e.g.

```
<include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
  <template1>{GUID here}</template1>
  <template2>{GUID here}</template2>
</include>
```

Comment: Please see my edit. I added a snippet as where should I add this code.